# Solving recurrence equation that appear in biology

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am struggling to solve this recurrence equation,

$$a_{n}(1-sa_{n-1}^{2})+sa_{n-1}^2-a_{n-1}=0$$

where the parameter $s\in[0,1]$ and the initial condition $a_{0} > 0$ is close to 1. I have graphed it in matlab and it decreases really fast even if $a_{0} = 0.9$. Any idea on how to solve this will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Note: if $a_{0}=1$, then $a_{n}=1, \forall n$.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve this"?

Comment: If $a_0=0$ then $a_1(1-0)+0-0=0$ implies $a_1=0$ and thus $a_n=0, \forall n$

Comment: Of course, $a_{0} > 0$, sorry didn't specify this.

Answer (score 1):

You have $a_n = \dfrac{a_{n-1} - sa_{n-1}^2}{1- sa_{n-1}^{2}} = a_{n-1} \left(\dfrac{1-sa_{n-1}}{1- sa_{n-1}^{2}}\right)$ providing that $sa_{n-1}^2 \not = 1$

If $0 \le a_{n} \le 1$ and $0 \le s \le 1$ and $sa_{n-1}^2 \not = 1$, then the sequence is decreasing (possibly weakly) and bounded below by $0$, so there must be a limit

Solving $a(1-sa^{2})+sa^2-a=0$ leads to $a=0$ or $1$, so these are the only possible fixed points.  So, given the sequence is decreasing,

- if  $0 \le a_{n} \lt 1$ and $0 \le s \le 1$ then the limit must be $0$
- if  $a_{n} = 1$ and $0 \le s \lt 1$ then the limit must be $1$

Comment: Yes, that's true. I am looking for a closed-form solution. Thanks for looking into this.